# Showing that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+\sin^2(\theta)} = \pi\sqrt{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+\sin^2(\theta)} = \pi\sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: Hint: use the t-formula. No complex analysis is necessary.

Comment: Although complex analysis makes this question a lot easier :P ... in my opinion

Comment: The trick really boils down to using the fact that $\sin(\theta) = \frac{z-1/z}{2i}$ where $z = e^{i\theta}$ gives |z| = 1$. This is essentially what Git Gud does.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\gamma \colon[-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb C,\theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$ and use the residue theorem after proving that$$\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(\theta)}\mathrm d\theta = 4i\int_\gamma\dfrac{z}{z^4-6z^2+1}\mathrm dz=4i\int_\gamma\dfrac{z}{(z^2-2z-1)(z^2+2z-1)}\mathrm dz.$$